# How to click an element using xpath and showmodal

Tags: java, selenium

I need to click on the element that has the following code

```
<img src="images/myImage.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="ToggleAdvanceSection();ShowModal();" alt="">
```

**this element is visible on the screen. it is an image. once clicked, a modal widow shows up**

I tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@onclick='ToggleAdvanceSection();ShowModal();']")).click();
```

However it throws an error : `not visible` . I made sure that the page is loaded . . still the same thing

How to click  this element ?

Comment: We can't click element which is not visible. What is the error/output you get?

Comment: it is visible .   `inspect element` in chrome shows this element

Comment: Inspect will show all the elements, but in order to click the element through selenium, the element needs to be visible (check the property of the element after it is initialized). In your post you mentioned it is not visible?

Comment: apologies, i meant it throws an error :  `element is not visible`

Comment: Please provide your full HTML snippet. I guess there are *many* elements that have the same xpath and the 1st element is not visible. And, your needed image is not the 1st one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium would not be able to click the element if the element is not visible. This is by design.

Comment: this element is visible on the screen. it is an image. once clicked, a modal widow shows up

Comment: There are two different things here. 
1. All the elements are visible in the HTML when we inspect through any browser. 
2. For each element (or for its parent) there would be a style property associated whether the element is visible or not as part of code. So selenium would use that property before clicking an element.